# Interactive blocks bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have block in my page like below

```
<!-- Interactive Block -->
    <div class="block">
        <!-- Interactive Title -->
        <div class="block-title">
            <!-- Interactive block controls (initialized in js/app.js -> interactiveBlocks()) -->
            <div class="block-options pull-right">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="block-toggle-content"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Blog Post"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
            <h2><strong>Latest</strong> Blog Post</h2>
        </div>
        <!-- END Interactive Title -->
        
        <h4><strong><a href="#">Blog Post Title</a></strong></h4>
        <h5>Monday March 1st 2021</h5>

        <!-- Interactive Content -->
        <!-- The content you will put inside div.block-content, will be toggled -->
        <div class="block-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non suscipit odio. Mauris ac nisi ultrices, fermentum ipsum sit amet, pharetra diam. Proin erat leo, lobortis vitae eros vehicula, luctus tincidunt neque. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vel mi feugiat, ut fermentum felis tincidunt. Integer sagittis interdum magna nec suscipit. Nulla mollis turpis lacus, quis luctus purus finibus et. Donec nec eleifend nisl. Suspendisse porta felis varius leo tempor, ut gravida felis iaculis. Pellentesque rhoncus neque diam, eu malesuada nunc malesuada quis. Maecenas vel magna sed diam dignissim faucibus a a ex. Quisque quis elit dui. Sed tincidunt leo vitae faucibus dignissim. Phasellus in quam vitae erat molestie gravida quis ut elit. Mauris hendrerit, purus sed pharetra euismod, massa sapien malesuada nulla, eget venenatis nibh nibh nec leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin ipsum ante, luctus a mi et, viverra ornare sem.</p>
            
          <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer et vehicula purus, sit amet vestibulum ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vulputate arcu risus, sed posuere metus vehicula tristique. Aenean vel risus non sapien elementum aliquet. Nam dolor tortor, tempus ac risus ac, aliquet consequat magna. Nulla vitae justo pulvinar, congue augue ac, volutpat arcu. Cras ipsum ex, feugiat a odio ac, tempus ultrices nisi. Nunc neque metus, hendrerit a felis ac, condimentum gravida turpis. Pellentesque in leo eu turpis iaculis placerat sit amet sit amet arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt tellus nisl, in euismod odio tempor id. Duis velit diam, vestibulum vel nulla nec, vehicula suscipit odio. Mauris massa justo, vehicula id convallis sed, laoreet non metus. Aenean placerat urna blandit, pellentesque orci condimentum, molestie nibh.</p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- END Interactive Content -->
    </div>
    <!-- END Interactive Block -->
```

and javascript code related it like this

```
var interactiveBlocks = function() {

        // Toggle block's content
        $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-content"]').on('click', function(){
            var blockContent = $(this).closest('.block').find('.block-content');

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                blockContent.slideDown();
            } else {
                blockContent.slideUp();
            }

            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });

        // Toggle block fullscreen
        $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-fullscreen"]').on('click', function(){
            var block = $(this).closest('.block');

            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                block.removeClass('block-fullscreen');
            } else {
                block.addClass('block-fullscreen');
            }

            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });

        // Hide block
        $('[data-toggle="block-hide"]').on('click', function(){
            $(this).closest('.block').fadeOut();
        });
    };
```

When my page load, its showing full block and when I click on arrow button, its hide content. Instead I want keep content hidden and only want show it on button click. I have tried to add code like

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```

on my function start but its not working. I think I am missing something and does not getting idea how I can handle this. Let me know if someone here can help me for same.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s best if provide a working version of your code using the [Code Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) function when asking a question – it's easier to see what's happening.

A couple of quick notes on the code you did provide: there’s nothing calling the interactiveBlocks function, so your `on click` listeners aren’t getting attached, and you’re using jQuery’s slideDown / slideUp, which are in the regular jQuery, but not in the slim version that Bootstrap requires.

If you add the `active` class to the anchor tag you’re using as a button (`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-default active"…`) and set the `block-content` div to `display: none;` (`<div class="block-content" style="display: none;">`) and call the interactiveBlocks function, it should work for you.

```js
var interactiveBlocks = function() {
    var tmp;
    // Toggle block's content
    tmp = $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-content"]');
    tmp = $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-fullscreen"]');
    $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-content"]').on('click', function() {
        var blockContent = $(this).closest('.block').find('.block-content');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            blockContent.slideDown();
        } else {
            blockContent.slideUp();
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    // Toggle block fullscreen
    $('[data-toggle="block-toggle-fullscreen"]').on('click', function() {
        var block = $(this).closest('.block');

        if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            block.removeClass('block-fullscreen');
        } else {
            block.addClass('block-fullscreen');
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    // Hide block
    $('[data-toggle="block-hide"]').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.block').fadeOut();
    });
};

interactiveBlocks();
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Interactive Block -->
<div class="block">
    <!-- Interactive Title -->
    <div class="block-title">
        <!-- Interactive block controls (initialized in js/app.js -> interactiveBlocks()) -->
        <div class="block-options pull-right ml-5">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-default active" data-toggle="block-toggle-content"><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-alt btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Blog Post"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <h2><strong>Latest</strong> Blog Post</h2>
    </div>
    <!-- END Interactive Title -->

    <h4><strong><a href="#">Blog Post Title</a></strong></h4>
    <h5>Monday March 1st 2021</h5>

    <!-- Interactive Content -->
    <!-- The content you will put inside div.block-content, will be toggled -->
    <div class="block-content" style="display: none;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non suscipit odio. Mauris ac nisi ultrices, fermentum ipsum sit amet, pharetra diam. Proin erat leo, lobortis vitae eros vehicula, luctus tincidunt neque. Phasellus tincidunt ligula vel mi feugiat, ut fermentum felis tincidunt. Integer sagittis interdum magna nec suscipit. Nulla mollis turpis lacus, quis luctus purus finibus et. Donec nec eleifend nisl. Suspendisse porta felis varius leo tempor, ut gravida felis iaculis. Pellentesque rhoncus neque diam, eu malesuada nunc malesuada quis. Maecenas vel magna sed diam dignissim faucibus a a ex. Quisque quis elit dui. Sed tincidunt leo vitae faucibus dignissim. Phasellus in quam vitae erat molestie gravida quis ut elit. Mauris hendrerit, purus sed pharetra euismod, massa sapien malesuada nulla, eget venenatis nibh nibh nec leo. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Proin ipsum ante, luctus a mi et, viverra ornare sem.</p>

        <p>Nulla facilisi. Integer et vehicula purus, sit amet vestibulum ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vulputate arcu risus, sed posuere metus vehicula tristique. Aenean vel risus non sapien elementum aliquet. Nam dolor tortor, tempus ac risus ac, aliquet consequat magna. Nulla vitae justo pulvinar, congue augue ac, volutpat arcu. Cras ipsum ex, feugiat a odio ac, tempus ultrices nisi. Nunc neque metus, hendrerit a felis ac, condimentum gravida turpis. Pellentesque in leo eu turpis iaculis placerat sit amet sit amet arcu. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt tellus nisl, in euismod odio tempor id. Duis velit diam, vestibulum vel nulla nec, vehicula suscipit odio. Mauris massa justo, vehicula id convallis sed, laoreet non metus. Aenean placerat urna blandit, pellentesque orci condimentum, molestie nibh.</p>
    </div>

    <!-- END Interactive Content -->
</div>
<!-- END Interactive Block -->
```

With the code you're using for showing the block, you do have to be sure to have the `active` class on the button (that's what the JavaScript looks at to decide if it should be showing or hiding the text), AND you have the text styled as `display: none` (you can't use Bootstrap's d-none class as it has !important and jQuery won't be able to override that).

Comment: Hello sir! Its working like charm! I have accepted as well up voted the answer. Thanks a lot!